Kitten would play around more than eat?
A relative of mine found a kitten on the side of the road and is feeding it wet cat food for kitten, however, the kitty seems more interested in playing with the other kitties than eating. Even when the other kitties are eating, the kitten is trying to play with them instead of eating.
Due to their work schedule, they can't bring it to the vet yet so in the meantime I took it upon myself to ask here on what could possibly be the reason for this? They said it eats probably twice a day if that (they've had the kitten for 2 days) but the other cats eat throughout the day.
They said it's most likely 3 to 4 weeks old.

It's a kitten.
Different cats have different preferred eating schedules, and have different levels of confidence that food will be there when they get to it rather than having to gobble it the moment it appears.
And kittens (like any young animal) are still exploring the world, figuring out what it is and what they are and what they can do, so they are going to spend a lot more time playing than an older cat would.
If in doubt, take it to the vet. Always. It's possible that the kitten is ill, and a bit nauseous, and is less interested in food for that reason. But just wanting to play when it wants to play rather than stopping for a scheduled meal sounds like every human toddler I have ever known.
If the other cats can be trusted not to over-eat, it may be worth keeping a bowl of dry food continuously available, so the kitten can nibble whenever it slows down enough to do so.
